# Deploying application on with 2 Front End Server and 2 Database servers which are clustered

Tags: front-end, database-server

I have following questions with regards to multiple servers in Farm configuration.

1. I want to create a web application , will it be created across both
   the Web Front End Servers?
2. If I want to restore a database through Sharepoint Management Shell
   with the Restore command, will it restore the database on both the
   clustered databases without me doing anything?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a web application, it will be on both WFE but you need a load balancer infront of both WFE.

[SharePoint will restore](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/administration/restore-a-content-database) the database on primary sql server. you need to manually configured it to always on group from SQL server....or if you managing the Cluster from SharePoint then you have to configure it [from management shell](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-2016-managing-alwayson-availability-group/).